# CLGeocoder reverseGeocodeLocation in China

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

I'm using CLGeocoder reverseGeocodeLocation to get addresses from coordinates, it seems that in China is returning "The geocoder has failed: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=8 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 8.)" for loc : 50.820835 4.385551".
Has someone had issues with reverseGeocodeLocation in China starting from iOs 5.0?

Answer (score 0):

kCLErrorDomain error 8 is kCLErrorGeocodeFoundNoResult.

I had similar issues in Romania, but,
the code below should return at least the city, if not the full address.

```
[_geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location
                    completionHandler:
     ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

    // Iterate trough placemarks

    CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:i];                 
    NSDictionary *addressDict = [placemark addressDictionary];

    //addressDict should contain your info.



}];
```

Comment: I'll try that, so you're ignoring NSError *error when is set?

Comment: I'm careful when kCLErrorNetwork occurred. 
(The network was unavailable or a network error occurred.)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in China you can only reverse geocode locations in China.

Answer (score 0):

China government has been blocking Google and its services for a long time. For residents in northern America, please do not expect to have access detailed geographical info of China. Both sides block each other.